# class constructor initialization?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to understand the following code.(I am learning C++)

```
class DefaultDevice : public Device {
  public:
    DefaultDevice() :
      ui(new DefaultUI) {
    }
  private:
    RecoveryUI* ui;
};
class DefaultUI : public ScreenRecoveryUI {
 ...
}
```

I am having little trouble understanding **ui(new DefaultUI)** part.
As I understand it is part of initialization before DefaultDevice() constructor is executed.
Then, from my understanding, it is going to call ReocoveryUI constructor with **new DefaultUI** argument.  But, RecoveryUI class does not have any constructor with such  argument.(sorry for not posing RecoveryUI class. it's too long :( if anyone interested in, it is Android Open source code)

so what does this 'new DefaultUI' do?

Comment: Try reading a good C++ programming book. They will explain better than we can in a few minutes. Also, compile with `g++ -Wall -g` and use the debugger `gdb` to step by step in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is a valid and working code, It seems `RecoveryUI` is a base class for `DefaultUI`.

`ui(new DefaultUI)` creates an object and assigns it to `ui`.

So, `ui` points to its child object.

Comment: so ui(new DefaultUI) creates an RecoveryUI object or DefaultUI object?    If it was ui(new DefaultUI()), I can see that it is passing DefaultUI object to RecoveryUI constructor...

Comment: It creates `DefaultUI` object but holds it as a `RecoveryUI`.

Comment: @Todd `new DefaultUI` creates a `DefaultUI` and returns a pointer to `DefaultUI`. `ui` is initialized with that address, so you end up with a pointer to `RecoveryUI` pointing to a `DefaultUI` object..

Comment: @juanchopanza ok, it makes sense to me now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It is not run *before* the ctor, it is part of the ctor. It's called an initializer list and it's used to initialize the (non-static) member variables of a class.